# My modal is giving the error Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to understand what's causing this error

controller code

```
 $scope.newManager = function (isValid) {
        // making a manager
        $http.post('/manager-create', {
            name: $scope.name,
            cellPhone: $scope.phone,
            group: $scope.group.value,
            manager: true
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available

            // reset the form fields
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.phone = '';
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'okay.html',
                controller: 'OkayModal',
            });


        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            console.log(response); //error
        });

    };
```

and here's the modal itself

```
angular.module('management').controller('OkayModal', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.okay = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('okay');
    };
});
```

Whenever I make a new manager, a modal pops up. But for some reason I'm getting this error!

Comment: The error you are seeing usually happens when some place in your code attempts to do a digest (by calling `apply`) when a digest is already in progress.  Is there any chance that your modal is somehow doing this?

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I'll edit my modal code as well. It's just a normal dismiss button.